# How to use Promise instead of setTimeout with some data from VUEX in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuex

I want to show pdf file on my modal my creating document url builder and some pdfId, that I stored in the VUEX, and on my vue component I mapped action, and mounted the function using setTimeout, because I have to wait `pdfId` to be loaded then pass it into `fetchPdfFile` but I'm being told that that's wrong way, instead I have to use Promise.
Here's my code

document url vuex,

```
const documentUrlBuilder = new DocumentUrlBuilder()

const document = {
   namespaced= true,
   state: () => ({
     pdf: {
       repository: 'medscareInc',
       url: null,
     }
   }),
   mutations: {
     updateDocumentUrl(state, url) {
        state.pdf.url = url
     }
   },
   actions: {
     async fetchPdfFile({commit, state}), pdfId) {
        const response = await documentUrlBuilder.getDocumentById(
           state.pdf.repository,
           pdfId
        );
        commit('updateDocumentUrl', response.url);
     }
   }
```

`getDocumentById` is a document url builder function

and this is my vue component

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    pdfUrl() {
      return this.$store.state.pdfs.pdf.url
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const pdfId = this.$store.state.document.pdf.pdfId // fetching from another vuex
      this.fetchPdfFile(pdfId)
    }, 2500)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('pdfs', {
      fetchPdfFile: 'fetchPdfFile',
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

I am being told that I cannot use setTimeout, instead I have to use Promise, how do I do that?

Comment: It looks like with your `setTimeout()`, you are waiting for `pdfId` to become available. Is that right? How is that value loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I have to wait pdfId to be loaded, then pass it into fetchPdfFile

Comment: And how is `pdfId` set? I think that is missing form the code you shared, right? Also, does it make sense to have `fetchPdfFile()` load a different `pdfId` than the one set in state? If so, this would mean that the `pdfId` in the store might not match the stored `url`, event though `url` is loaded from `pdfId`

Comment: pdfId is set in different vuex state, you don't have to worry about that, tha's not the main concern of this topic, the main topic is to use Promise instead of setTimeout

Comment: You are using `setTimeout` to wait for `pdfId`, and it is this timeout you want to replace with a promise. So it is literally the main concern of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your promise is resolved. You could use `await` or use `then`. If you use await, your mounted hook must be async as well. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

If you want to learn more about promises have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
...
async mounted() {
    const pdfId = this.$store.state.document.pdf.pdfId
    await this.fetchPdfFile(pdfId)
},
...
```

Comment: I tried it but not working

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using a timeout, after which you assume `pdfId` will be available. The problem with this approach is that users will wait several seconds, even if the `pdfId` was loaded immediately, and in case of a longer delay, your code fails when `pdfId` is still not available after the timeout.

Instead using a Promise allows you to wait for `pdfId`, and immediately continue once the value is provided. Structurally, this would look something like this:

```
async mounted(){
  const pdfId = await this.loadPdfId()
  this.fetchPdfFile(pdfId)
}
```

which is structurally equivalent to:

```
mounted(){
  return this.loadPdfId().then(pdfId => this.fetchPdfFile(pdfId))
}
```

With this, `mounted()` returns a Promise, and when the promise is resolved, the provided value will be used as argument for `this.fetchPdfFile()`. Using async/await behaves just the same, but it gives you (arguably) more readable code.

From the code you shared, it is not clear how `this.loadPdfId()` would look like, but I am sure you can figure it out yourself.

Also, as a tip, it looks like you are using the store incorrectly. For example, you would load the pdf's url every time your component is mounted, but the idea of a store is that you have to load data just once (because it is stored once you have loaded it, hence the name). Similarly, when you change `pdfId`, the URL of the previous pdf is gone. All in all, it looks like you are using the store as a global variable, where you dump in local values, which is not the purpose of a store. So check if you need the store at all, it might just make things worse for you.

Without the store, you might end up with something like this:

```
async mounted(){
  const pdfId = await this.loadPdfId()
  this.pdfUrl = await this.fetchPdfUrl(pdfId)
}
```

Does that make sense? Does it help?

Comment: where does ```loadPdfId()``` come from?

Comment: The code you shared does not  indicate how  `loadPdfId()` looks like. It is the code your `setTimeout()` waits for, written as a function returning a Promise, similar as the examples above